# How to prove this operation is unique

Tags: group-theory

> Given a prime number $p$, an operation “$*$" is defined over the $N^{+}$ structure of Abel group and satisfies:
>
> 1. $a*b\le a+b$
> 2. **All nonzero elements have order $p$**
>
> Question: Is this operation unique?

I think this is the case. But I can't explain why.

This problem is from Algebraic problem book exercise by (zhi xu yang),It is said the author choose AMM problem 1978

Comment: What is a uniqueness operation?

Comment: mean that this opetarion is only one

Comment: If I understand correctly, your "operation" $*$ operates on $\{0,1,2,3\dots N-1\}$ and has the two properties stated.  We are asked to prove that the properties stated are sufficient to make the result of the "operation" be unique, which then allows us to call it an operation. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes,@RossMillikan,That's my mean.+1

Comment: I think Ross must be deep into the mind reading business.

Comment: I also believe we are given that $a*b=b*a$ from the Abel group structure.

Comment: So, if I understand the question correctly, you're asking whether there's a unique group structure on $X = \mathbb{N}^{\geq 0}$ such that (a) $x.y = y.x$ for all $x, y$; (b) $x.y \leq x + y$, where the left side is ordinary addition in $\mathbb{N}^+$; and (c) Every $x\not = 0$ has order exactly $p$? (I'm assuming here that $0\in \mathbb{N}^+$ is the zero element of $X$.)

Comment: @anomaly: I'm not sure we are promised a group structure, but saying order $p$ may promise it.  I took order $p$ to mean if you did $a*a*a*\dots*a$ with $p$ operations you got back to $a$.  I think a group structure makes it work.  If you post that as an answer and nobody comes up with one that doesn't use that, I'll award the bounty.

Comment: @RossMillikan: The group structure is the best reading I can come up with for "defined over the $N^+$ structure of Abel group." (And it's certainly not enough of an answer to merit receiving a bounty.) Honestly, if this question weren't assigned a bounty, I'd flag it as being unclear and vote to close.

Comment: @anomaly: I agree it is unclear.  I believe the Abel group just tells us that $*$ is commutative.  I found my reading interesting, but couldn't finish the proof, which is why I offered a bounty.  china math:  could you clarify-are we given that $*$ is a group operation?  Associativity and inverses would then be given-that would help a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a start.  It needs completion.  I will assume $p \gt 2$.  Similar arguments will work for $p=2$, but some details need to be cleaned up.

First note $0*0=0$ by property $1$, so $0$ is of order $1$, so all other elements have order $p$.  Then $0*1=1, 1*1=2$ because otherwise $1$ has a lower period.  Now $1*n=n+1$ for $n \lt p-1, 1*(p-1)=0$ to get the period right.  Now we can show $2*2=4$ and so on.  We can continue to fill in the table and will show that $*$ is exactly addition $\pmod p$ for $a,b \lt p$.  If $p=N$, we are done.

If $N \gt p$, we have $p$ in our set.  We can't have $1*p$ be anything less than $p$ except $2$ because we get a lower period for $1$.  In general, we can show that if $a \lt p, a*p \lt p$, then $a*p=a+a$  I haven't seen how to exclude this.  Once we do, we will get that there must be at least $p^2$ elements by following this route.  I believe eventually we will show that there must be $p^n$ elements and $*$ is addition in the field of $p^n$ elements.

Added:  If we are given that $*$ is an Abelian group operation we can get there. $1*p$ cannot be anything less than $p+1$ because we can't have $1*p=1*n$ for distinct $n,p$ in a group.  We continue up the same way finding that $*$ is addition $\pmod p$ up to $2p-1$.  As $p$ must have period $p$, we can show that all the elements up to $p^2-1$ are in the group and $*$ is the claimed addition in the field of $p^2$ elements up this high.  Then if $p^2$ is in the group we must have everything up to $p^3-1$ and so on.